# Fiware: How to browse organization containers in Fiware Lab

Tags: fiware

I've currently working with ObjectStorageGE and I am able to publish and edit my objects inside the Object Storage using CDMI. For tracking pourposes I want to browse in FiwareLab -> Cloud -> Containers the objects that users of the organization has published. However, I cannot access to containers published to Organization tenant (or I cannot find to way to do it...) using the Organization owner account.

PS: I can browse containers and objects correctly in FiwareLab if I publish them using my own user tenant.

Answer (score 0):

From FIWARE help-desk:

"I don’t understand why you talk about “Organisation tenant” on one side and about “my own user tenant” on the other side. What do you mean with those different tenants? Are you using the same tenant in both sites (cloud portal and API)?Take into account that only some tenants are visible in the cloud portal (the default cloud tenant associated to a user)"

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?

Answer (score 0):

In general, in order to access containers, the user must belong the tenant (account) that owns that container. This is to impose separation of access between tenants. In recent versions of Swift Object Storage there are mechanisms to allow access to others, but these are not enabled in the versions running in the Fiware lab.